# Sending ArrayList from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I'm new to Android, i am trying to send some data from database using bundle and parcelable to fragment to display recyclerview and layouttab. with the dummy data i can show the recyclerview within 2 tabs. but when i trying to using data from database that i fetch it from activity, i got some trouble to send the data i got to fragment.

I tried many solution in the post that have similarities. but until this time i can't quite get the right solution.

this is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private static final String URL = "http://myweb.com/api/getID.php?id=1";
private String[] ar_id, ar_stat;
private int arr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //Add Fragment
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentActive(), "Active");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentHistory(), "History");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    getDataOrder();

}

private void getDataOrder(){
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray list = response.getJSONArray("result");
                ArrayList<Active> arrayList = new ArrayList<Active>();
                arr = list.length();
                ar_id = new String[arr];
                ar_stat = new String[arr];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
                    JSONObject data = list.getJSONObject(i);
                    ar_id[i] = data.getString("id");
                    ar_stat[i] = data.getString("status");
                    arrayList.add(new Active(ar_id[i], ar_stat[i]));
                }

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("ac_array", arrayList);
                bundle.putString("test", "123");
                FragmentActive fragmentActive = new FragmentActive();
                fragmentActive.setArguments(bundle);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Fetching ERROR", "ERROR");
        }
    }
    );
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

}

Also, this is the object class, **Active.java**

```
public class Active implements Parcelable {
private String status;

public Active(){

}

public Active(Parcel in){
    super();
    readFromParcel(in);
}

public Active(String id, String status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.status = status;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Active> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Active>() {
    public Active createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Active(in);
    }

    public Active[] newArray(int size) {

        return new Active[size];
    }

};

public void readFromParcel(Parcel in){
    id = in.readString();
    status = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(status);
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

And this is the fragment class, **FragmentActive.java**

```
public class FragmentActive extends Fragment {

View v;
private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
private ArrayList<Active> lstActive;
//private ArrayList<Active> getArray;

public FragmentActive() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<Active> activeArrayList = new ArrayList<Active>();
    if (getArguments()!=null) {
        activeArrayList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ac_array");
        String test = getArguments().getString("test");
        Log.d("List", test);
    }else{
        Log.d("List", "Null?");
    }
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.active_fragment, container, false);
    myrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.active_recyclerview);
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), ***activeArrayList***);
    myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    myrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Dummy Data
    lstActive = new ArrayList<>();
    lstActive.add(new Active("1", "1"));
    lstActive.add(new Active("2", "0"));
    lstActive.add(new Active("3", "1"));
}
```

}

When I run the app, there was no error at all, just the recyclerview didn't show up, but when i change the ***activeArrayList*** on the FragmentActive.onCreateView to dummy ArrayList, the dummy data showing up.

Then, I try to print the data i got from database, It shows. But when I try to print arrayList from MainActivity, this is what i got from run debug text

> D/Debug List: [com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@79e903c,
>   com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@8dde1c5, com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@4a1571a]
>
> I/System.out: [com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@79e903c,
>   com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@8dde1c5, com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@4a1571a]

Are they the 3 rows from database? because the database that i selected shows 3 rows. What should i do to fetch, send and show the data?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

D/Debug List: [com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@79e903c, com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@8dde1c5, com.xxx.xxx.app.Active@4a1571a] this is your activeArrayList.
The values inside are the objects from your list.
And you should probably make a custom recycler view adapter.
The one you used is for an array list of strings.
So make a recyclerviewadapter and make it in such a way you can show the required data.

Answer (score 1):

You creating a Fragment but not adding it anywhere, you have to populate your ViewPagerAdapter ONLY after you have data:

```
            FragmentActive fragmentActive = new FragmentActive();
            fragmentActive.setArguments(bundle);
            adapter.addFragment(fragmentActive//
```

The other one you added to the ViewPager is empty and will be if you don't use the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have a method in fragment to update `ArrayList<Active>` data, which would
update recycler view's adapter data.

which could be like
in fragment:

```
public void updateListData(ArrayList<Active> list){
recyclerAdapter.updateData(list);
}
```

in your Recycler adapter have updateData method like:

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<Active> list){
//assign list to your data in adapter
this.lists = list;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call `updateListData` on FragmentActive after getting data in onResponse.
have FragmentActive as class level variable.

Comment: I tried this, but i got, non static method error on RecyclerViewAdapter, if i change the method to static, the FragmentActive's one is error.

Comment: How are you trying??

Comment: In fragment also make recyclerview adapter class level variable.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I normally follow with this kind of app is to have an `ArrayList` populated in the activity (from the database) and then have the `Fragment` pull the data from activity using an interface (or casting the `getActivity()` of the `Fragment` to the class of your main activity) when the fragment becomes visible (see `setUserVisibleHint()` for this).

About your code:

1) I see you initialize the viewpager with `FragmentActive` and `FragmentHistory`, but at that point they have no arguments.

2) In `getDataOder()` you create the argument for `FragmentActive` and you create a new instance of the fragment, but it seems it is lost because nothing else is done with it.

3) Also, bear in mind that `ViewPager` manages the lifecycle of the `Fragments` you add to it, so I think wired things can happen if you set arguments to a fragment used in a `ViewPager`, because the most likely is that the instance you created and set the arguments on, at some point, will be removed, and replaced with a new instance that lacks the arguments. (I should test this, but it is what I believe will happen).

Comment: I'm still new to android and i'm trying to understand this, somehow i got the gist of it, do you have good tutorial reference or example app that has similarities with mine? the tutorial i found so far still didn't give me best solution.